# how to read file modal window in flask

Tags: amazon-s3, flask

s3 called up txt file and showed it to new window was successful.
I want to show you the contents of this txt file using a modal pop-up. I've tried it, but I don't show it 'body'.
Thanks very much for your help.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" action="{{ url_for('information') }}" method="POST" >
              {{ my_text }}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
@app.route('/information', methods=['POST'])
def information():
    key = request.form['key']
    my_bucket = get_bucket()
    file_obj = my_bucket.Object('parameter.txt')
    my_text = Response(file_obj.get()['Body'].read(), mimetype='text/plain',)
    return render_template('html_with_modal.html', my_text=my_text)
```

Comment: @Avian Thank you for your reply. I've reflected your advice, but nothing has changed. I would appreciate your advice. The text has been modified with the changed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this.

Firstly, save your response in a variable, like

```
my_text = Response(file_obj.get()['Body'].read(), mimetype='text/plain',)
```

then you need to render your template and pass your text in as an argument, like

```
 return render_template('html_with_modal.html', my_text=my_text)
```

and then just like you wherever you want to place my_text in your template, you can put something like

```
   <div class="modal-body" open="{{ url_for('information') }}" method="POST" >
   {{my_text}}
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I've reflected your advice, but nothing has changed.
I would appreciate your advice. 
The text has been modified with the changed code.